# Throttle in Kafka Streams SessionWindows

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

By default, `.windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(...))` will return every new incoming record. So, how could I wait for atleast 1 second before returning the last result of current session window?

I'm trying with word count example:

```
        final KStream<String, String> source = builder.stream("streams-plaintext-input");

        final KStream<String, Long> wordCounts = source

                // Split each text line, by whitespace, into words.
                .flatMapValues(value -> Arrays.asList(value.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).split(" ")))

                // Group the stream by word to ensure the key of the record is the word.
                .groupBy((key, word) -> word)

                .windowedBy(SessionWindows.with(Duration.ofSeconds(10)))

                // Count the occurrences of each word (message key).
                .count(Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.Long()))

                .suppress(Suppressed.untilTimeLimit(Duration.ofSeconds(1), Suppressed.BufferConfig.unbounded()))

                // Convert to KStream<String, Long>
                .toStream((windowedId, count) -> windowedId.key());

        wordCounts.foreach((word, count) -> {
            System.out.println(word + " : " + count);
        });
```

This is the input of producer and result in client, which is actually wrong:

```
$ bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic streams-plaintext-input
>hello kafka stream

(nothing)

>hello kafka stream

hello : 1
kafka : 1
stream : 1

>hello kafka stream

hello : null
kafka : 1
stream : 1
```

How could I fix that? Thanks a lot for reading my question :)

Comment: Have you figure out how to achieve your use case? I am trying to achieve it as well.

Comment: By the way, your question is more like "debounce" instead of "throttle" :)

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/68273851/4161471

Answer (score 1):

`KTable#suppress()` operator is your friend for this case.

Check out the docs and a detailed blog post about it:

- Section "CONTROLLING KTABLE EMIT RATE" in https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html
- or https://kafka.apache.org/22/documentation/streams/developer-guide/dsl-api.html#window-final-results
- https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-streams-take-on-watermarks-and-triggers

Comment: @matthias-j-sax - I have read all those 3 documents but I am not able to figure out how pro achieve use case mentioned above. Can you please advise me? Thanks in advance

Comment: "Not able to figure out" is not very descriptive -- what behavior do you observe? What parameters did you set?