# How do debounce Spring KafkaListener

Tags: java, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have a topic that contains server registrations but it may get several messages at once because the servers run in a cluster, but I only need the last one.  So I was thinking I wanted a debounce similar to [Debounce kafka events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68273851/debounce-kafka-events) but I want to implement it for the `KafkaListener` provided by Spring.

The data is `compacted`, but it takes time for the segment to shrink and data still comes in pretty quickly.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds more like Log Compaction feature would fit your requirements: https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#compaction